# Are we able to find easily the matrix from adjoint matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm curious about whether we are  able to find the main matrix from adjoint matrix. And the other thing what I'm curious is whether Adjoint matrix is unique or not.

Thanks in advance for you about this simple question.

Comment: If you have given $A^\dagger$, then $(A^\dagger)^\dagger = A$. Concerning the second question: If you have given $A$ and $b$, then $(A, b)$ is unique. If $(A', b')$ is another augmented matrix, it automatically follows that $(A, b)_{i, j} = (A', b')_{i, j}$ for all $i, j$. Hence, $A = A'$ and $b = b'$.

Comment: To be clear, when you say "adjoint", are you referring to the conjugate transpose of the matrix?  Or are you referring to the [adjugate matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix#:~:text=In%20linear%20algebra%2C%20the%20adjugate,which%20is%20its%20conjugate%20transpose.) which appears for instance when calculating the inverse of a matrix?

Comment: really sorry for english. yes what I wish to say adjugate matrix. (the transpose of cofactor matrices). I really don't like linear algebra but trying to get its advantages to learn

Comment: For that, note that all we need is to prove the map is not one-to-one.  Notice that $\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$ both result in the same adjugate matrix.  So, given the result of the mapping there was no way to get an unambiguous input.  Less trivial examples can be made as well with some effort.